# Power bi group ranking

Tags: powerbi

Can you help me? I want the rank to be assigned within the filtered range (filter by date). Tell me, please, what am I doing wrong? CustomerSaleIndex1 = VAR CurrentOrderDate = \'public _smsnt_delete\'[date_transaction] VAR CurrentOrderTr = \'public _smsnt_delete\'[transaction_id] VAR CurrentCustomerKey = \'public _smsnt_delete\'[card_number] RETURN RANKX(FILTER(ALLSELECTED(\'public _smsnt_delete\'); \'public _smsnt_delete\'[card_number] = CurrentCustomerKey);\'public _smsnt_delete\'[date_transaction];;ASC;Dense)

Answer (score 0):

In terms of your separator in the filter function, you are using the semicolon "**;**" over the comma separator "**,**"?

Also you've declared CurrentOrderDate as a variable, why not use it. On the other side of things, why is CurrentOrderTr even declared? As you don't use it in the function:

```
CustomerSaleIndex1 = 
VAR CurrentOrderDate = 'public _smsnt_delete\'[date_transaction] 
VAR CurrentCustomerKey = 'public _smsnt_delete\'[card_number] 


RETURN 
RANKX(FILTER(ALLSELECTED('public 
_smsnt_delete\'),'public_smsnt_delete\'[card_number] = CurrentCustomerKey),
CurrentOrderDate,,ASC,Dense)
```

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dax/rankx-function-dax